# Can qmake support a folder hierarchy for a Visual Studio solution?

Tags: visual-studio, qmake

I'm developing my project in Visual Studio and I'm using qmake to create the solution file. I'm trying to organize the solution by introducing sub-folders to contain similar projects. However, the solution file produced by qmake has a folder hierarchy of only one level.

Is there any way to configure qmake to produce a folder hierarchy for Visual Studio, similar to the effect of "Add→New Solution Folder" in the Solution Explorer?

**Edit**: to clarify, suppose I have this directory structure:

```
MainDir
   +--- GroupDir1
   |       +--- ProjectDir1
   |       +--- ProjectDir2
   +--- GroupDir2
           +--- ProjectDir3
```

I want the folder hierarchy in the solution *as seen in Visual Studio* to reflect just that, but this is the solution I manage to generate using qmake:

```
Solution
   +--- ProjectDir1
   +--- ProjectDir2
   +--- ProjectDir3
```

Comment: can you post your qmake hierarchy (only the relevant parts)??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what you are probably looking for is to add the following in your pro file

```
CONFIG -= flat
```

Take a look at the [Qt documentation on this option](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#config)

As an example, you can also [take a look at this pro file](http://code.google.com/p/ballelevgenerator/source/browse/trunk/NEW/NEW.pro) which uses this option

Comment: was looking for this for months...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG  += ordered

SUBDIRS +=  project1\
        project2\
            ...
        projectn
```

The [subdirs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmake-variable-reference.html#template) template is used for building targets in subdirectories. You can add subdirectories using the variable [SUBDIRS](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmake-variable-reference.html#subdirs).

In general is it a good idea to add `CONFIG  += ordered`, in case you have depedencies between projects (like a library).

You can also use `.pri` files, the equivalent of headers for project files, to share variables between your sub-projects.

***EDIT : TRY THIS***

Create `maindir.pro` with

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG  += ordered

SUBDIRS +=  GroupDir1\
        GroupDir2\
```

then `groupdir1.pro` with

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG  += ordered

SUBDIRS +=  ProjectDir1\
        ProjectDir2\
```

and then `groupdir2.pro` with

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG  += ordered

SUBDIRS +=  ProjectDir3
```

This is guaranteed to work with Qt Creator, cannot test it with visual-studio...

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that's exactly what I'm doing right now, and it still gives me that 1-level hierarchy that I want to avoid. Each `.pro` file is already using the `subdirs` template.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have a hierarchy in your .pro/pri but it gets "converted" to a single level structure in visual studio. But since the pro/pri is what's actually used by qmake its not really single/level flat (your source files don't get moved).

Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: In the structure of the VS project they're one level, but the physical location isn't is what I mean by "converted". It looks like totem is on the money with the CONFIG -= flat option :)